# Rethink DB Cross Cluster Replication

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdb-ruby, rethinkdb-javascript

I have 3 different pool of clients in 3 different geographical locations.

I need configure Rethinkdb with 3 different clusters and replicate data between the (insert, update and deletes). I do not want to use shard, only replication.

I didn't found in documentation if this is possible.

I didn't found in documentation how to configure multi-cluster replication.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that multi cluster is just same a single clusters with nodes in different data center

First, you need to setup a cluster, follow this document: http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/start-a-server/#a-rethinkdb-cluster-using-multiple-machines

Basically using below command to join a node into cluster:

```
rethinkdb --join IP_OF_FIRST_MACHINE:29015 --bind all
```

Once you have your cluster setup, the rest is easy. Go to your admin ui, select the table, in "Sharding and replication", click Reconfigure and enter how many replication you want, just keep shard at 1.

[image: sharding and replication]

You can also read more about Sharding and Replication at http://rethinkdb.com/docs/sharding-and-replication/#sharding-and-replication-via-the-web-console

Comment: Thank's, but Unfortunately didn't work.  By this way is possible only write and read from the primary replica. I think there is another way.