# Multiple primaries in a rethinkdb cluster

Tags: rethinkdb

I've got two sets of servers hosted on different continents belonging to a rethinkdb cluster. The primary belongs to one set, so any query generated from the other set takes a lot of time to execute under the default read and write consistency modes.

I was wondering if there is anyway I could make separate clusters for each of the sites and cross-replicate between the clusters? (I took a look at [Rethink DB Cross Cluster Replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326888/rethink-db-cross-cluster-replication), but there doesn't seem to be such a solution.)

If not, is there a way I could setup two primaries in a cluster, one for each of the sites without breaking consistency guarantees?

Answer (score 2):

You can have two primaries in a cluster either by having two tables, one for each set of servers, or by sharding a single table.  You can control which server set the primary ends up in by using server tags (https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/sharding-and-replication/).

Comment: Is there anyway I can have the primaries for different shards coming from different server-sets?

Comment: You can write `table.config().update({shards: [{primary_replica: 'foo', replicas: ['foo', 'bar']}, {primary_replica: 'bar', replicas: ['foo', 'bar']}]})`.

Comment: I'm getting an error : e: Expected type NUMBER but found ARRAY